# How can I clone the repository into mine while keeping them updated from where I cloned it

Tags: git, github, repository

I want to clone a repository say "A" into my repository say "B" and make changes while doing that I also want to keep pulling the latest changes from the repository "A" from where I have cloned my repository "B". For example, after cloning the repository after 6 months I have make changes and the contributory to the repository "A" from where I cloned also made changes, so now I want to update my repository from where I cloned it 6 months back. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+update+cloned+repository